# PHP: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.18

Tags: php, mysql, apache, centos

I'm Set Crontab :

```
[root@root mysql]# crontab -l
5 *  *  *  *  php /home/admin/public_html/scheduleSendMail.php
```

But Not Execute PHP code!

```
[root@root mysql]# php /home/admin/public_html/scheduleSendMail.php 
php: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


[root@root mysql]# rpm -qR postfix
```

find :

```
..
libmysqlclient.so.16  
libmysqlclient.so.16(libmysqlclient_16)  
..
```

I am using the Centos And DirectAdmin

```
PHP v: php-5.3.3-14.el6_3.i686
mysql v: mysql-5.1.66-2.el6_3.i686
centos v: CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
```

Comment: There are a couple things that could be wrong. Either you don't have the mysql client libraries installed. Or PHP is compiled against the wrong version of the libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

code:

```
#ls -l /usr/lib/mysql | grep libmysqlclient.so
```

outPut:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Dec 21 21:41 libmysqlclient.so -> libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Dec 21 21:41 libmysqlclient.so.16 -> libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1524000 Dec  7 18:27 libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0

#ln /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0  /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.18
```

Not Work !

But :

```
#ln /usr/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.16.0.0  /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.18
```

It's Work very Good :D

Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

Php is compiled against the wrong mysql lib.

I suggest you to check if the php executable is the one provided with the rpm package.

You can also try a dirty workaround, go to the directory where the libmysqlclient.so.16 is located and write:

ln -s libmysqlclient.so.16 libmysqlclient.so.18

Comment: MerC. But Can not even see my version php.#php -v --> Error libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open....I've done something that you said But Not work.

Answer (score 0):

A better option is remove your php and install the version 5.3.23:

1. yum remove php
2. wget http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/latest.rpm
3. rpm -ivh latest.rpm
4. enable the webtatic repository and disable the rhea repository (/etc/yum.repos.d/)
5. yum install php